# How to handle Apollo Graphql query error in Vue.JS?

Tags: graphql, vue-apollo

I am using Vue.js with Vue-Apollo and trying to fetch shared member list using query. I am using the graphQL service in backend.

I am using apollo 'error' function to handle GraphQL error. When the request is made with invalid input, I can see the errors in the network tab, I can see the JSON for the custom errors messages. But I can't console the errors in 'error' function.

Here is the apollo query that is used to fetch shared member list -

```
apollo: {
    sharedMembers: {
      query: gql`
        query item($uuid: ID) {
          item(uuid: $uuid) {
            ...itemTemplate
            members {
              ...member
              permission
            }
          }
        }
        ${ITEM_TEMPLATE}
        ${MEMBER}
      `,
      variables() {
        return {
          uuid: this.$route.params.uuid,
        }
      },
      update(data) {
        return data.item.members
      },
      error(error) {
       console.log('errors', error)
      }
    },
  },
```

The network response I got -

[network_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJlB1.png)

Comment: Is error showing as `undefined`?

Comment: @DanielRearden, no nothing printed in console info. But getting this error.



`Error: GraphQL error: Internal server error
    at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:63)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:1003)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:130)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:165)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:219)
    at bundle.esm.js:865
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:865)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:130)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:165)`

Comment: @DanielRearden, I have also attached network response image above in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using graphQLErrors

You could get the errors by looking in the error object for graphQLErrors:

```
error(error) {
  console.log('errors', error.graphQLErrors)
}
```

or

```
error({ graphQlErrors }) {
  console.log('errors', graphQLErrors)
}
```

## Using apollo-error-link

You can use apollo-error-link to help solve your problem if the above doesn't work, [docs here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling/).

Here's an example from the docs and I added to it in the networkErrors section to show what you can do to edit the error message you see in your error block, or catch block if its a mutation.

```
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";

const link = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );

  if (networkError) {
    // Add something like this to set the error message to the one from the server response
    networkError.message = networkError.result.errors[0].debugMessage

    console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`)
  };
});
```

And then in your code:

```
error(error) {
  console.log('error-message', error.message)
}
```

The console should then log your `debugMessage` from the server.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately i couldn't find out how i'd handle errors in such of graphql method call, but as an option you could provide `onError` method to `ApolloClient` constructor options. first argument is the error object. hopefully it may help. like so..

```
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
  onError(err) {
    console.log(err)
  },
})
```